# Debug assertion failed, C++ vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector

I know this question has been asked before but even after looking at all the others I can't seem to figure this out. I am getting "vector subscript out of range" for the following code:

```
double forward_price(int number_divs, std::vector<double> *dividends, std::vector<double> *time_dividends)
{
    int i = number_divs - 1;
    for (; i >= 0 & (*time_dividends)[i] > 0.0;)
        i--;

    for (; i >= 0 & (*time_dividends)[i] > 0.0; i--)
    {
        forward_px -= (*dividends)[i]
    }

    return forward_px;

}

int number_divs = 3;
std::vector<double> dividends = { .5, .6, .58 };
std::vector<double> time_dividends = { .04, .198, .6 };

double forward_div = forward_price(3, &dividends, &time_dividends);
```

As far as I can tell it is coming from the second for statement and works when I change that one to i>=1. I'm able to call time_dividends[0] and dividends[0] so I can't tell why this isn't working.

Comment: Also, why do you use pointers to vectors and why do you feel the need to pass their length as an extra parameter? This is not C.

Comment: I thought it would be more efficient to pass a pointer, but I could be mistaken. I recently modified the code to use vectors instead of arrays so passing the length was a relic of that.

Comment: If you really want output parameters, use a reference instead of a pointer. For input-only parameters that might be big, use a `const` reference.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll try that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single `&` in

```
i >= 0 & (*time_dividends)[i] > yte_forward
```

is a *"bitwise and"*, you probably want the *"logical and"* `&&`.

Comment: Both instances of this.

Comment: Note that the logical and (&&) doesn't evaluate the right hand side if the left is false while the bitwise and does and that evaluation produces the access fault.